# error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'B'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Following code gives a compilation error (at least when using MS VS 2008) for line "e=f" in main():

> error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'B'

```
class A {
public:
    A() { }
    static const double x;
};
const double A::x = 0.0;

class B {
public:
    B() : x(0.0) { }
    const double x;
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    A c,d;
    B e,f;

    c = d;
    e = f;

    return 0;
}
```

The default assignment operator should be generated for both classes, A and B !?

> in 12.8.10: "If the class definition does not explicitly declare a
>   copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The implicitly generated operator would recursively assign each non-static member. However, `x` is `const`, so it can't be assigned to. This prevents the implicit operator from being generated (specifically, it causes it to be defined as deleted).

This is specified in C++11 12.8/23:

> A defaulted copy/move assignment operator for class X is defined as deleted if X has:
>
> - ...
> - a non-static data member of const non-class type (or array thereof), or
> - ...

(Although I just noticed that your compiler predates C++11; the rules are similar, but specified in different language, in older dialects with no concept of "deleted" functions).

If you want an assignment operator for a class whose members (or base classes) can't be reassigned, you'll have to define it yourself.

In `class A`, the constant member is static, so doesn't form part of an object. Therefore, it doesn't prevent an (empty) object from being assigned to.

Answer (score 4):

field `'x'` is of const-qualified type of `const double`, the default assignment operator will be meaningless and is implicitly  *deleted* here

Answer (score 2):

The obvious difference between class A and B is const member x beeing static vs. non-static.
Assignment to a const variable is/should be impossible in any case.

The compiler obviously tries to generate the default assignment operator method for class B and silently decides to not generating one, as member x does not allow assignment.

Took me quite a long time to find out this ...

BTW: If you omit the initialization of x in class B , compiler is smart enough to find out this mistake.

Comment: Yes you answered your own question. You get a badge (but no rep) if you accept your answer.