# error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I've looked at other threads but they don't seem to be applicable to my case. Here's the class. The macros and Unreal Engine 4 related.

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FWeaponInfo
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    FWeaponInfo() { }

    FWeaponInfo(AWeaponActor* InActor);

    UPROPERTY()
    TSubclassOf<AWeaponActor> Class;

    UPROPERTY()
    FName Name;

    UPROPERTY()
    FText Description;

    UPROPERTY()
    UTexture2D* Icon;
};
```

I've commented out all members including the constructor and I still get the error. This is an odd one..

Comment: Here is the possible cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606813/error-c2582-operator-function-is-unavailable-in-b

Comment: I don't have any const members so I don't think so.

Comment: Here you have more explanations:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797454/why-do-i-get-this-error-c2582-operator-function-is-unavailable-in-b-whe

Comment: You need to provide an assignment definition for a `GENERATED_BODY`

Comment: in your question you have macros that are not defined, how are we supposed to help you? BTW you shouldn't use macros in C++

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error and tracked it down to a missing include, so it may be worth double checking that you're including the header for the USTRUCT in question.

I'll also mention I'm using GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY() instead of GENERATED_BODY() - though I don't recall if that makes a difference.